# File Linking: Excel to Access to Excel

Tags: excel, database, access

My organization is small and uses SharePoint to store our shared files enabling us to access shared files from each of our desktops.

However, when we link files while they are on our desktop they automatically grab our usernames (e.g. C:\Users[USERNAME]\SharePoint\Databases\ExampleDatabase.accdb) so if someone else opens the file with the link they can't refresh the information without re-creating the link. This is obviously not an ideal situation and the primary issue.

What we are looking for is a solution where we can link Excel content to Access DB's and link Access DB's to Excel pivot tables while storing all the files in SharePoint while allowing multiple users to open, use, and refresh the files. So if user A links a file to Access and saves the Access file, user B will be able to download that Access file and refresh the content from the Excel file.

Limitations:
- No one in the organization can write macros and we hope to keep any DB management in house
- We need a solution that can handle a large DB file. DB had about 1.5m observations at this point with it increasing quarterly.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.